# Need help in this Weird JSON

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON as below

```
{
   "shippingGroupListJson":[
      {
         "lineId":123,
         "shippedTo":{
            "country":"US"
         },
         "cartons":1,
         "group":"4",
         "shipInscription":{
            "municipalInscription":"",
            "inscriptionType":"",
            "stateInscription":"",
            "suframaInscriptionNumber":"",
            "inscriptionBranch":"",
            "contributorClass":"",
            "inscriptionDigit":"",
            "inscriptionNumber":""
         },
         "shipCartonDetails":[

         ],
         "shippedContact":{
            "firstName":"Mjjkk",
            "email":"nob@gmail.com",
            "fax":"--",
            "phone":"80-121",
            "lastName":"Henry"
         },
         "mobilityShipStatus":"Not Yet Shipped",
         "shipDate":"13 Dec 2014"
      },
      {
         "lineId":0,
         "shippedTo":[

         ],
         "cartons":0,
         "group":"5",
         "shipInscription":[

         ],
         "shipCartonDetails":[

         ],
         "shippedContact":[

         ],
         "mobilityShipStatus":"",
         "shipDate":"",
         "shipStatus":""
      }
   ]
}
```

If you see in this above JSON in key **"shippedTo"**, when there is value , I get a JSON Object and when no value is present then i get a Blank JSONArray.

I need to fix this issue. I cannot communicate with the service team to change this as they won't make changes to it. Can any one tell me how can i do the required changes.

I know this is not the rite way, but i need to do something..

I tried using `String.replaceAll(oldChar,newChar);`

Comment: I guess you could simply try to get the `shippedTo` key as a JSONObject and if that fails(exception that you'd need to check for) revert and fetch it as a JSONArray.

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you for your reply but I am using gson library to parse the entire JSON. I cannot change that at this point because the json i have posted here is just a small part of the parent json and many more keys are there.

Comment: Best way to parse json is to convert json to class check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Then you'd need to use your initial approach to replace the empty json array return. Try something like this: `yourJSONResponseAsString.replaceAll("\"shippedTo\":\[\s*]", "\"shippedTo\": {}");` to replace the json array with an empty json object.

Comment: @Luksprog I tried your code, I get this error in eclipse "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )".

Comment: Try `yourJSONResponseAsString.replaceAll("\"shippedTo\":\\[\\s*\\]", "\"shippedTo\": {}")` .

Comment: Pls show your parsing code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are using GSON, in which case `JsonArray` and `JsonObject` are both subclasses of [`JsonElement`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html).

But you do not say if you are using the DOM or Streaming technique with GSON.

You should show your parsing code, or the class that's being automatically used for the parsing.

In the meantime, based on what you have said, I would define my `shippedTo` field in my class as an `Object`. That should parse correctly (if using DOM), and after that you can analyse exactly what you have in that field.

Instead of:

```
  private MyCountryType shippedTo;
```

Have:

```
  private Object shippedTo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check its type at runtime i.e

```
JSONObject jsPar=new JSONObject(json_data);
JSONArray jsarrPar=js.getJSONArray("shippingGroupListJson");


for(int i=0;i<jsarrPar.size();i++){
JSONObject js= jsarrPar.getJSONObject(i);   
if(js.get("shippedTo") instanceof JSONArray){
    //Treat it as an array
    }
    else{
    //Treat it as a single json object
    }
}
```

Furthermore if you need it as an JSONObject immaterial of it being a single element then do this to get your customized string

```
   JSONObject jsPar=new JSONObject(json_data);
    JSONArray jsarrPar=js.getJSONArray("shippingGroupListJson");


    for(int i=0;i<jsarrPar.size();i++){
    JSONObject js= jsarrPar.getJSONObject(i);   

    JSONObject js=new JSONObject(json_data);
    if(js.get("shippedTo") instanceof JSONArray){
        js.put("shippedTo",new JSONObject()); //purge the original array with this new blank element
    }
    else{
      //Do your normal stuff    

    }
}
    String curmodstring=jsPar.toString();
```

Hope you get the general idea.